# Image aligned right with text components stacked to the left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, blazor

I'm currently building a website with Blazor Pages on the .NET platform. I'm new to using HTML and CSS, and I decided to use the Bootstrap CSS library to work on my first website. I'd like to have a text container aligned to the left of my overall jumbotron component along with an image in the right. Something like this:
[image: Quick example of what I'd like for my site.]

My website currently resembles this:
[image]

(the hair is a photo of me, not going to upload the whole image)
The image itself is rather large, so ideally I'd like to work with scaling. I know the img-fluid class can handle scaling within a parent container, but I'm not sure why it's not scaling down.
Here's my current HTML.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome to my site!</h1>
        <div class="container align-items-start">
            <p class="lead text-left">Welcome to my personal site. I hope to use this as a place where you can learn more about me, my projects, and my ideas.</p>
            <p class="lead text-left">I am just learning web development, so many aspects of this website won't be perfect. I hope that this place can serve as a living example of my progression!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="/Images/Headshot2020.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Image of Matt Marlow"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you're looking for or create layouts in general.

I would strongly recommend avoiding using 3rd party libraries that you're not familiar with to build your webpage layout. You might be able to get help on this particular page, but you will get stuck again as soon as you want to create the next one.

It's kind of like trying to build a car without knowing how to weld.

You should read about using Flex (bootstrap is based on that). It might sound intimidating but it's very straightforward.

Start by building some blocks and see how they react with different settings applied to it. Once you feel comfortable, start expanding it and reach the design you want.

a helpful tip:
For each container or "box" you're building - apply some colorful background or border. This will allow you to see exactly which container is being affected and how by every change. So the thumb rule is: Each div gets it's own color.
Once you're satisfied with the layout, just remove all the colors and start inserting content.

Link explaining how to work with css flexbox
[CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

And here's a snippet using basic flex to build the layout you wanted

```css
body, html{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.main-container{
  background: gray;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: flex;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left-panel{
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

.right-panel{
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px lime;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.title{
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.content{
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px magenta;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.image{
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="left-panel">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="title">
        Welcome to my site !
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Lorem ispum, some random text!
        </br>
        This is a markup example for my question
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-panel">
    <div class="image">
      A picture of me !
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should the css classes you posted go directly into my `site.css` file, or should I have multiple .css files?

Comment: The mystery deepens. I ran your html/css in my website, and did not get the result that SO's run code snippet offers. I suspect this is a product of Blazor.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap saves a lot of time and work-- setting breakpoints for a gazillion things is hard.

But when it comes to these kinds of problems, you need to KNOW enough html/css does and how it works.  In particular, learn how flex layout works.

Then you will be able to choose the correct Bootstrap classes, knowing that your site will conform to best practices for a dynamic layout.

Answer (score 1):

Use `float-end` on the image this will allow the text to flow around the image. I moved the image above the heading to align their tops.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="/Images/Headshot2020.jpg" class="img-fluid float-end col-4" alt="Image of Matt Marlow" />
    <h1>Welcome to my site!</h1>
    <p class="lead">Welcome to my personal site. I hope to use this as a place where you can learn more about me, my projects, and my ideas.</p>
    <p class="lead">I am just learning web development, so many aspects of this website won't be perfect. I hope that this place can serve as a living example of my progression!</p>
</div>
```

[image: Example:]
BTW: `jumbotron` is obsolete.
Photo by Alison Wang on Unsplash